# SUM Ranges depending on value with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I'm trying to do the following with VBA. Imagine I have some data as it follows:

[image]

I would like my final result to be the sum of every data that is between "BEGINDATA" and "ENDDATA". So it would look like this:

[image]

My goal is to obtain the green data and write it next to "ENDDATA"

Any idea or suggestion?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm working with a macro. I have a long code trying to get my final result. These is one of the steps where I got stucked. 
I was thinking to do a bucle and everytime you find "BEGINDATA" select the next row until you find "ENDDATA" -1 row. But I am not seeing it clear how to do it...Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, BeginData As Long, EndData As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To Lastrow

            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "BEGINDATA" Then
                BeginData = i
            ElseIf .Range("A" & i).Value = "ENDDATA" Then
                EndData = i
            End If

            If EndData > BeginData Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("B" & BeginData + 1 & ":B" & EndData - 1))
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Another Version:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, BeginData As Long, EndData As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To Lastrow

            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "BEGINDATA" Then
                BeginData = i
            ElseIf .Range("A" & i).Value = "ENDDATA" Then
                EndData = i
            End If

            If EndData > BeginData Then
                With .Range("B" & i)
                    .Value = Application.Sum(Sheet1.Range("B" & BeginData + 1 & ":B" & EndData - 1))
                    .Interior.Color = vbGreen
                End With
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That is simply perfect! It totally works :) Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using `Find` which will be faster then looping

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim BeginData As Range, EndData As Range
    Dim FirstBeginAddress As String

    ' Update with your range
    With Sheet1.Columns(1)
        Set BeginData = .Find(what:="BEGINDATA", after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not BeginData Is Nothing Then
            FirstBeginAddress = BeginData.Address
            Set EndData = .Find("ENDDATA", after:=BeginData)
            Do
                Debug.Print "BeginAddress", BeginData.Address
                If Not EndData Is Nothing And EndData.Row > BeginData.Row Then
                    Debug.Print "EndAddress", EndData.Address
                    '' For Formula
                    EndData.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(BeginData.Offset(1, 1), EndData.Offset(-1, 1)).Address & ")"
                    '' For value
                    'EndData.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Application.Sum(Range(BeginData.Offset(1, 1), EndData.Offset(-1, 1)))
                    Set EndData = .Find("ENDDATA", after:=EndData)
                Else
                    Err.Raise 998, "Demo", "Unable to find Data Footer"
                End If
                Set BeginData = .Find("BEGINDATA", after:=BeginData)
            Loop Until BeginData Is Nothing Or BeginData.Address = FirstBeginAddress
        Else
            Err.Raise 999, "Demo", "Unable to find Data Header"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```